# 503 (Service Unavailable) - IIS 7.5 deployed MVC web application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, deployment, iis-7.5, web-deployment

Every 24 hours or so, we receive a 503 from our IIS 7.5 web server that hosts our MVC application.

I read some related articles and checked if the Application Pool/Identity had the necessary permissions and was a part of the IIS_USR (or whatever it is called) group.

The event log reports that the ASP.NET worker process crashed. This is the information from the event log:

```
Log Name:      Application
Source:        Application Error
Date:          5/14/2013 11:15:58 PM
Event ID:      1000
Task Category: (100)
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      SERVER_MACHINE_NAME
Description:
Faulting application name: w3wp.exe, version: 7.5.7601.17514, time stamp: 0x4ce7a5f8
Faulting module name: unknown, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x00000000
Exception code: 0x00000000
Fault offset: 0x1ccbc2de
Faulting process id: 0x2640
Faulting application start time: 0x01ce51338e238a4b
Faulting application path: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
Faulting module path: unknown
Report Id: e8120b0c-bd26-11e2-9313-001f290b5f7a
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Application Error" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="0">1000</EventID>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>100</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2013-05-15T06:15:58.000000000Z" />
    <EventRecordID>4265</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>SERVER_MACHINE_NAME</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>w3wp.exe</Data>
    <Data>7.5.7601.17514</Data>
    <Data>4ce7a5f8</Data>
    <Data>unknown</Data>
    <Data>0.0.0.0</Data>
    <Data>00000000</Data>
    <Data>00000000</Data>
    <Data>1ccbc2de</Data>
    <Data>2640</Data>
    <Data>01ce51338e238a4b</Data>
    <Data>C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\w3wp.exe</Data>
    <Data>unknown</Data>
    <Data>e8120b0c-bd26-11e2-9313-001f290b5f7a</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

**Deployment Environment:**

**Web Server:** IIS 7.5

**.NET Framework:** v4

**MVC version:** 4

**Windows Server:** Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard

Help appreicated.

Comment: Just an idea, the pool recycles every 29h by default. What if you manually recycle the pool? Do you get the same error?

Comment: I've set log notifications to be generated for all kinds of applicaiton pool recylcing. When the pool recycles due to inactivity or a scheduled recycle, it automatically restarts itself and creates a new worker thread. So, I don't see a 503. This is some serious business within the application code. I am going to get a memory dump, I think, using the IIS Diagnostics & Debugging tools and find out what the problem is.